# How do you turn on constant interpolation for keyframes in blender?

Tags: animation, keyframes, interpolation

Following a tutorial with my own keyframes and the lecture was talking about how he is using constant interpolation for keyframes so blender doesn't interpolate the in-betweens like below. Where do I find the option? I am using blender alpha right now so sorry in advance if this is inconvenient.

[image: What I have right now]

[image]

What I want to do is above. I did try to go to graph editor I think and pressed N then went to active keyframe and turned interp to Constant. It did not work however I probably did something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The settings in the <kbd>N</kbd> region only apply to the *active* keyframe (usually the one selected last).

To change the interpolation for all selected keyframes, press *Header > Key > Interpolation Mode* in the graph editor header, or press <kbd>T</kbd> while hovering over the graph editor.

Comment: I fix it by pressing T over graph editor and change everything to constant. Thank you.